# Adding two If Me statements together

Tags: vba

I have two statements which, on their own, work perfectly. I am trying to get them to work together in one statement but get an error message. They are

```
Private Sub NextDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.NextDue > Me.EndDate Then
    MsgBox "Check Rent Review Date"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

 If Me.NextDue < Date Then
    MsgBox "Date in Past"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but get the Compile Error: "Else without If". I've tried to add ElseIf but get another Compile Error: "Expected: expression". Can they be done together?

Comment: Remove the `End Sub` in the middle of your code.

Comment: Oh, @YowE3K you missed around 45 points by posting this as comment! :/. Anyway, funny thing is there's no `Else` in the code!

Comment: @A.S.H - someone else has done the work for me :D  I've edited my comment into their answer so I could then +1 them for saving me having to type the full code.

Comment: That's rather interesting. I would have expected the compiler message to have been something like "Illegal outside procedure" and to highlight the `If Me.NextDue < Date Then` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `End Sub` that you currently have in the middle of your code:

```
Private Sub NextDue_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 If Me.NextDue > Me.EndDate Then
     MsgBox "Check Rent Review Date"
     Cancel = True
 ElseIf Me.NextDue < Date Then
     MsgBox "Date in Past"
     Cancel = True
 End If

End Sub
```